How to Run moveVis Frame Animation in Parallel?
I have a large movestack object that I would like to turn into a .gif animation. Currently, the estimated time to run the animate_frames() function is ~22 hours. If possible, I would like to run my code in parallel to speed that up a bit. I found this page from the moveVis package which includes functions to enable multicore usage for moveVis. My problem is that after running the provided code and then running my script, my estimated time to run the animate_frames() function remains ~22 hours. This leads me to believe that I may be doing something wrong or missing a step. Does anyone know what else I need to do to parallelize my code? Apologies if it's obvious, still new to parallelizing. Thanks!
#load packages
library(moveVis)
library(move)


## example code to set up multicore processing provided by moveVis


# enable multi-core usage automatically
use_multicore()

# allow disk use with default directory and maxiumum of 50 frames in memory
use_disk(frames_to_disk = TRUE, n_memory_frames = 50)


## example code to create movement animation also provided by moveVis. This dataset is from the moveVis package and is much smaller than my actual dataset, so it shouldn't take very long to run. 


data("move_data", package = "moveVis") # move class object

# align move_data to a uniform time scale
m <- align_move(move_data, res = 4, unit = "mins")

# create spatial frames with a OpenStreetMap watercolour map
frames <- frames_spatial(m, path_colours = c("red", "green", "blue"),
                         map_service = "osm_stamen", map_type = "watercolor", alpha = 0.5) %>% 
  add_labels(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") %>% # add some customizations, such as axis labels
  add_northarrow() %>% 
  add_scalebar() %>% 
  add_timestamps(type = "label") %>% 
  add_progress()

# animate frames
animate_frames(frames, out_file = "moveVis.gif")

  


Interesting. When I download the package with devtools::install_github("16EAGLE/moveVis") and run your code using default tiles (osm - streets), the 188 frame animation generates in about 2 minutes. I wonder if the issue is related to pulling the osm_stamen tiles. (Maybe related to Stamen's 2023 offloading of the hosting to Stadia Maps? https://maps.stamen.com/stadia-partnership/)

sorry, I should've specified in my question that my example code uses a dataset provided by the moveVis package and not my actual dataset, so it shouldn't take nearly as long to run.

How many frames are you trying to make? How long does each frame take when you try a shorter test?

The full animation is 2093 frames. I can run a subset of 50 frames in about 30 minutes, which seems in line with the ~22 hours for the full 2093 frames. I realize it's a lot of frames, I was just wondering if there was a way to speed up the processing time

Do you have a sense what is making each frame so slow to render? >30 seconds per frame seems relatively slow.

I think it's because I had to create a custom timestamp label. The timestamp function in movevis uses a format that my supervisor wasn't a fan of, so I had to write a loop to add custom date annotation text to each frame along with a white rectangular background for the date. Before I added that, the whole animation ran in about three hours, which was much more acceptable than 22

Sounds like it might be faster to render those separately and composite afterwards using magick.

Do you mean I should plot and save all 2093 individual frames, for example as 2093 .png files, and then try to combine all 2093 files? Wouldn't plotting and saving each individual frame still take forever? Apologies if that's not what you meant, still trying to learn my way around magick

“3 hours” to render without date notation text + “1min?” to render the text notations + “5min?” to composite the frames together to add the text to the map frames = << 22 hours.
